Why does my Angular router link bring me to the bottom of a page?
I use Angular 17 with SSR and standalone, I have my component challenges. I have a button and want to be redirected to editors. But each time, I land at the bottom of the page.
I tried lot of solutions without success.
my challenges.html
<a target="_blank">
          <button (click)="router.navigate(['/editors']);" class="btn secondary-btn">{{ "common.discover" | translate }}</button>
        </a>

my editors.ts
isBrowser = false;

  constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object) {
    this.isBrowser = isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId);

  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    if (this.isBrowser) {
      const element = document.querySelector('#editorpage');
      if (element) {
        element.scrollIntoView();
        console.log("Scrolled to #editorpage");
        element.scrollTop = 0;
      } else {
        console.log("#editorpage not found");
      }
    }
  }

I have a app.routes.ts
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'editors', component: EditorsComponent },
  { path: 'partners', component: PartnersComponent },
  { path: 'investors', component: InvestorsComponent },
  { path: 'telecoms', component: TelecomsComponent },
  { path: 'institutional', component: InstitutionalComponent },
  { path: 'universities', component: UniversitiesComponent },
  { path: 'influencers', component: InfluencersComponent },
  { path: 'ambassador', component: AmbassadorComponent },
];

and a configs.ts
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(routes),
    provideLottieOptions({
      player: () => import('lottie-web'),
    }),
    provideAnimations(),
    provideHttpClient(),
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      defaultLanguage: 'en',
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        // useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        useFactory: (http: HttpClient) => new CustomTranslateLoader(http),
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    }).providers!, provideClientHydration(), provideClientHydration(), provideClientHydration() ],
};

Thank you.

possible to share github repo?

The project is on Gitlab and in a private organisation. I wanted to make it public but don't have the rights

@NarenMurali I can add it in a drive zipped if ok for you.

For redirect the page with a scoll position on top. Please use the 'scrollPositionRestoration' option as 'top' in on config.ts page.
please replace the provideRouter(routes) with provideRouter(routes,withInMemoryScrolling({ scrollPositionRestoration: 'top' })) on config.ts page
Please change the below code on configs.ts
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {  providers: [
provideRouter(routes, withInMemoryScrolling({ scrollPositionRestoration: 'top' })),
provideLottieOptions({
  player: () => import('lottie-web'),
}),
provideAnimations(),
provideHttpClient(),
TranslateModule.forRoot({
  defaultLanguage: 'en',
  loader: {
    provide: TranslateLoader,
    // useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
    useFactory: (http: HttpClient) => new CustomTranslateLoader(http),
    deps: [HttpClient]
  }
}).providers!, provideClientHydration(), provideClientHydration(), provideClientHydration() ]};


Very strange, I just test it and it is not working. I still have the routerLink landing at the bottom of the target page.

Is it possible to create a demo on https://stackblitz.com/ then it will be helpful to solve this.

it will take so many time. Could I just provide a zip link ? or a repo  in gitalb ?

Okay, you can provide me with a zip or repo.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GA7O28SmGkvhibi6rRfu6XPi8S3XQ0CL/view?usp=sharing

I have checked and it's working with withInMemoryScrolling({ scrollPositionRestoration: 'top' }). I have created a video with a scrollPositionRestoration and without scrollPositionRestoration. And it's working Please check this video screen https://nimb.ws/48zKqEX

@Suba, thank you very much. It is working. Thanks a lot. Just last question :  I noticed that when I paste the url http://localhost:4200/editors, home is loaded first then editors pages. This brokes my SEO because subpages metadata are never collected. Please how could I do to load the subpage directly without loading the home first ?

I have checked but I'm not getting this type of issue. Can you share any scenario that I can replicate?

if you click on it, you will see the home first before the 2nd page: https://www.gara.co/investors
